# Microsoft Teams outgoing webhooks with AAD authentication

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am trying to use Teams outgoing webhook to interact with my web service which requires AAD authentication. In such a case, I am not able to figure out a way to implement the AAD authentication for outgoing webhooks. Does this mean outgoing webhooks cannot be used with AAD authentication?

Comment: Hi Derek,

Yes, you can implement AAD to your Web Service. Could you please have a look on this [sample code](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-outgoing-webhook).

Comment: @Rama-MSFT I do not think the sample code describes how to implement AAD authentication. Instead. It is still Teams outgoing hooks' HMAC authentication, see especially [this file](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-outgoing-webhook/blob/master/WebhookSampleBot/Models/AuthProvider.cs). But thank you though

Comment: Hi Derek, could you please have a look on below two documents.
1) [Webhook authentication using Azure Active Directory(AAD)](https://medium.com/faun/k8s-cluster-on-azure-integrates-with-azure-active-directory-aad-and-webhook-authentication-4220cbaee63b)
2) [Secure-webhook-delivery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/secure-webhook-delivery)

Comment: Hi Derek, outgoing webhook currently supports only HMAC token to validate incoming request. For AAD authentication, you have to build Bots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Copying for better visibility.**

Hi Derek, outgoing webhook currently supports only HMAC token to validate incoming request. For AAD authentication, you have to build Bots